# Javascript execute function in es6 class on extend

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

How can I execute a function that is aware of a newly created class's name which is derived from a certain parent at the time that the class is extended?

What I currently do:

```
class component {
    constructor() {
         // this.constructor.name returns the derived class name on instantiation
         // we need to register class components derived from component
         registerIfUnknown(this.constructor.name);
    }
}
```

However this means the `registerIfUnknown` function will be called every time we create a new instance of any subclasses of component. Is there a way to execute a method/function that understands what the class's name is whenever the `component` class is extended?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Also, why should a class care about classes that extend it?

Comment: The component itself doesn't care about the extended classes- but each of these components are ui components- the register function currently registers these new classes so they can be created via the textual data in the ui. I may just end up making a babel plugin if this isn't possible.

Comment: @wizebin The registration should be independent of the extension. Just make a `register(class extends Component {…});` call.

Comment: @Bergi I'll do that- it's better to be a bit more explicit about it anyways